# Nested Entity relation in Room database

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

> I have to save a ShopMenu(object) that can have multiple sections(List) and each section can have multiple Items(List) in it && and each item can have the parent (ShopMenu-> Object) again

**ShopMenu** can recursively be added under Item. So for that purpose I added parentId = -1 for the top MainMenu and for item Child **ShopMenu** `parentId = id(ShopSectionItemEntity)`

```
ShopMenu 
  - SectionA
     - ItemA
        - ShopMenu (again the parent one)
            - SectionE
                - ItemF
     - ItemB
  - SectionB
      - ItemA
      - ItemB
 - SectionC
      - ItemA
      - ItemB
```

**ShopMenuEntity.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = ShopMenuEntity.TABLE_NAME)
data class ShopMenuEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var level:Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_PARENT_ID)
    var parentId: Int = -1
) {
    companion object {

        const val TABLE_NAME = "shop_menu_table"
        const val COLUMN_ID = "menu_id"
        const val COLUMN_PARENT_ID = "parentId"

        fun mapHttpResponse(subMenu: NewShopMenuResponse,parentId: Int): ShopMenuEntity {
            return ShopMenuEntity(
                id = subMenu.id ?: -1,
                level = subMenu.level,
                parentId = parentId,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ShopSectionEntity.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = ShopSectionEntity.TABLE_NAME,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShopMenuEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("menu_id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("fk_menu_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
    indices = [Index("fk_menu_id")])
data class ShopSectionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    var id: Int= 0,
    var order:Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = SHOP_MENU_ID)
    var shopMenuID: Int
) {

    companion object {

        const val TABLE_NAME = "shop_section_table"
        const val COLUMN_ID = "id"
        const val SHOP_MENU_ID = "fk_menu_id"

        fun mapHttpResponse(section:Section,shopMenuID:Int,orderIndex:Int):ShopSectionEntity {

            return ShopSectionEntity(
                id = section.id,
                shopMenuID = shopMenuID,
                order = orderIndex

            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ShopItemSectionEntity.kt**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = ShopItemSectionEntity.TABLE_NAME,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShopSectionEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("fk_section_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
    indices = [Index("fk_section_id")]
)
data class ShopItemSectionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    val autoItemID : Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = SECTION_ID)
    var sectionID: Int,
    var itemOrder:Int,
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "shop_section_item_table"
        const val COLUMN_ID = "id"
        const val SECTION_ID = "fk_section_id"

        fun mapHttpResponse(item: Item, sectionID: Int,itemOrderIndex:Int): ShopItemSectionEntity {
            return ShopItemSectionEntity(
                autoItemID = item.id,
                sectionID = sectionID,
                itemOrder = itemOrderIndex
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In order to save it in one go I have added db like below

**ShopMenuDB.kt**

```
data class ShopMenuDB(
    @field:Embedded
    var shopEntity: ShopMenuEntity,
    @field:Relation(parentColumn = ShopMenuEntity.COLUMN_ID, entityColumn = ShopSectionEntity.SHOP_MENU_ID, entity = ShopSectionEntity::class)
    var sections: List<ShopSectionDB>,
)
```

**ShopSectionDB.kt**

```
data class ShopSectionDB(

  @Embedded
  var shopSectionEntity: ShopSectionEntity,
    @field:Relation(
    parentColumn = ShopSectionEntity.COLUMN_ID,
    entityColumn = ShopItemSectionEntity.SECTION_ID,
    entity = ShopItemSectionEntity::class
  )
  var shopSections: List<ShopItemDB>
)
```

**ShopItemDB.kt**

```
data class ShopItemDB(

    @Embedded
    var shopItemEntity: ShopItemSectionEntity,
    @field:Relation(
        parentColumn = ShopItemSectionEntity.COLUMN_ID,
        entityColumn = ShopMenuEntity.COLUMN_PARENT_ID,
        entity = ShopMenuEntity::class
    )
    //Am I adding below entity correctly
    var shopSubMenu: ShopMenuEntity?
)
```

**Edit**

I have also editted **ShopItemDB**

This data is a simple Menu for shopping . There isn't any need for ShopEntity.kt **for MikeT**

**ShopMenuDao.kt**

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(shopMenuEntity: ShopMenuEntity,shopSectionEntities: List<ShopSectionEntity>?, shopItems:List<ShopItemSectionEntity>)
```

> And I am inserting single shopMenuEntity . How could I get shopMenuEntity under item ? Do I have to insert list of shopMenuEntity here

[image]

Comment: I never said there was a need for a ShopEntity but apparently for **ShopMenuEntity** as per your code `parentColumn = ShopMenuEntity.COLUMN_ID`. and also since your edit `fun insertAll(shopMenuEntity: ShopMenuEntity,s ....`. As per the answer, it is unclear what you want and or what the structure schema is.

Comment: I simply want to save a parent Table in another table which was a sub child of it. Like Menu has sections and each section has items and each item can have the same parentTable . And it can go to further deep. All items are saving and fetching correctly except MainMenu in ShopItemDB

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to embed ShopMenuEntity in ShopItemSectionEntity . As far as I learn it entity cannot be embedded in another Entity

No.

Do I have to create ShopItemDB or use ShopItemSectionEntity?

It is not abundantly clear what you want. However, in regards to nesting then no as what you have works (but perhaps not as intended).

Using your code but adding the apparently missing **ShopMenuEntity** to be (based upon your other code):-

```
@Entity(tableName = ShopMenuEntity.TABLE_NAME)
data class ShopMenuEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    val id: Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_SMNAME)
    val smName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_PARENT_ID)
    val parent_id: Int=-1
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "shop_menu_table"
        const val COLUMN_ID = "id"
        const val COLUMN_PARENT_ID = "parent_id"
        const val COLUMN_SMNAME = "shop_menu_name"
    }
}
```

And using/adding the following `@Dao` annotated interface (to allow data to be inserted and extracted to get a list of **ShopMenuDB**s):-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(mainMenuEntity: MainMenuEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(shopMenuEntity: ShopMenuEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(shopSectionEntity: ShopSectionEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(shopItemSectionEntity: ShopItemSectionEntity): Long


    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${ShopMenuEntity.TABLE_NAME}")
    fun getAllShopMenus(): List<ShopMenuDB>

}
```

The the following Activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(MainMenuEntity(1))
        dao.insert(MainMenuEntity(2,1))
        dao.insert(MainMenuEntity(3,2))

        val sm1Id = dao.insert((ShopMenuEntity(1,smName = "SM001")))
        val sm2Id = dao.insert(ShopMenuEntity(2,smName = "SM002"))
        val sm3Id = dao.insert(ShopMenuEntity(3,smName = "SM003"))

        val se1id = dao.insert(ShopSectionEntity(1,sm1Id.toInt()))
        val se2id = dao.insert(ShopSectionEntity(2,sm1Id.toInt()))
        val se3id = dao.insert(ShopSectionEntity(3,sm1Id.toInt()))

        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(10,se1id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(11,se1id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(12,se1id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(13,se1id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(14,se1id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(20,se2id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(22,se2id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(23,se2id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(30,se3id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(ShopItemSectionEntity(31,se3id.toInt()))

        for (sm in dao.getAllShopMenus()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for(se in sm.sections) {
                sb.append("\n\tSHOP SECTION ID is ${se.shopSectionEntity.id} parent ID is ${se.shopSectionEntity.shop_menu_id}. It has ${se.shopSections.size} ShopItems. They are:-")
                for (si in se.shopSections) {
                    sb.append("\n\t\tSHOP Section ID is ${si.shopItemEntity.id} SECTION_ID is ${si.shopItemEntity.section_id}. It has ${si.shopMenus.size} ShopMenus. They are:-")
                    for (sm in si.shopMenus) {
                        sb.append("\n\t\t\tSM is ${sm.smName} ID is ${sm.id} parent ID is ${sm.parent_id}")
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","ShopMenu is ${sm.shopEntity.id} Name is ${sm.shopEntity.smName} Parent is ${sm.shopEntity.parent_id}. It has ${sm.sections.size} Sections. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

results in the log including:-

```
D/DBINFO: ShopMenu is 1 Name is SM001 Parent is -1. It has 3 Sections. They are:-
        SHOP SECTION ID is 1 parent ID is 1. It has 5 ShopItems. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 10 SECTION_ID is 1. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 11 SECTION_ID is 1. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 12 SECTION_ID is 1. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 13 SECTION_ID is 1. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 14 SECTION_ID is 1. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
        SHOP SECTION ID is 2 parent ID is 1. It has 3 ShopItems. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 20 SECTION_ID is 2. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 22 SECTION_ID is 2. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 23 SECTION_ID is 2. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
        SHOP SECTION ID is 3 parent ID is 1. It has 2 ShopItems. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 30 SECTION_ID is 3. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
            SHOP Section ID is 31 SECTION_ID is 3. It has 0 ShopMenus. They are:-
D/DBINFO: ShopMenu is 2 Name is SM002 Parent is -1. It has 0 Sections. They are:-
D/DBINFO: ShopMenu is 3 Name is SM003 Parent is -1. It has 0 Sections. They are:-
```

So as can be seen, the hierarchy is followed (albeit that the relationships result in 0 children being located, which is perhaps due to a misunderstanding of the relationships).

The resultant database, as per App Inspection shows:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added some changes to my question. Also have a look at ShopItemDB. There isn't any need for shopEntity as this data is to display a men like I share screenshot